# Github pull request displaying too many file changes

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request

I am doing some work on a branch created from `master`. I have recently performed a rebase of that branch on `master`.

Since then, github displays a lot of modified files and commits:

[image]

But when I perform a diff, only one line in one file is identified (which is correct):

[image]

It is becoming very hard to review the PR. Is this a bug? Else, how can I fix this? What is causing this?

Comment: Try this: `git fetch` then `git diff master..KL-2664-new-korm-api-migration`

Comment: I get the same difference

Comment: Compare with origin/master not local master, `git fetch` then `git diff origin/master..KL-2664-new-korm-api-migration`

Comment: You can checkout to master, Pull master `git checkout master; git pull origin master`. Now go back your `KL-2664..` branch and compare with local master.

Comment: origin/master is one's local copy of master...

Comment: master = local copy of master, origin/master = remote master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following procedure:

1. I checked out `master`, then performed `git pull`
2. Then I checked out `KL-2664` and performed `git pull`
3. Then I merged `master` into `KL-2664`
4. ...and committed the result.

It seems like there is a difference between performing a rebase on `master` and on `origin/master`.

Comment: Your local master was not updated (someone pushed changes to remote master that you were not pulled/updated into your local master). Another solution is to Pull `master` into your local `KL-2664` branch directly. `git checkout KL-2664`, `git pull origin master`; `git push origin KL-2664` !